# Awk - Match Values Between Two Files

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files that I am trying to compare, and create a final.txt file with data that exists from both of those files.

File1 - column 1 and File2 - columns 2 contain the value that I need to match between the two files.

So essentially, I am trying to -> take column1 from File1, if there is a match in column2 of file2, then write File1Column1, File1Column2 and File2Column1 to a new file called final.txt.

EXAMPLE

File 1

```
1000,Brian
1010,Jason
400,Nick
```

File 2

```
3044 "1000"
4466 "400"
1206 "1010"
```

output file to look like

```
1000,Brian,3044
1010,Jason,1206
400,Nick,4466
```

my test code not showing any result

`awk -F"[,]" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1","$2;next} ($2 in a){print a[$2]","$1}' file1.txt file2.txt`

I believe I should be able to do this with awk, but for some reason I am really struggling with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates answers. You had already accepted an answer previously. Unaccepting the answer, and then changing/adding to the question is disrespectful to users who have put in time to help you. Please refrain from doing that.

Comment: Thank you cigien. Another note: Duplicate link added could be taken as a reference but it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  gsub(/"/,"",$2)
  arr[$2]=$1
  next
}
FNR==1{
  FS=","
  OFS=","
  $0=$0
}
($1 in arr){
  print $0,arr[$1]
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{             ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  gsub(/"/,"",$2)    ##globally substituting " in 2nd field with NULL.
  arr[$2]=$1         ##Creating array arr with index of 2nd field and value of 1st field.
  next               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==1{              ##Checking condition if this is first line of Input_file1.
  FS=","             ##Setting FS as comma here.
  OFS=","            ##Setting OFS as comma here.
  $0=$0              ##Reassigning current line to itself so that field separator values will be implemented to current line.
}
($1 in arr){         ##Checking condition if 1st field is present in arr then do following.
  print $0,arr[$1]   ##Printing current line and value of array arr.
}
' file2 file1        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any lines that don't match between the 2 input files in your sample input/output so this may or may not do what you want for those cases:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]\",]+"; OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
{ print $0, map[$1] }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1000,Brian,3044
1010,Jason,1206
400,Nick,4466
```